# Using named query in orm.xml, getting error No identifier specified for entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I'm trying to store my named queries outside of my application.  Everything I've read so far says to put the queries in orm.xml.  So I've done that, like so:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...   
    <entity class="com.blah.mapdb.repository.ResultRepository">
        <table name="ResultRepository.getMapForTarget" />
        <named-query name="getMapForTarget">
        <query>
                <![CDATA[
                Big giant query goes here
                </query>
        </named-query>
    </entity>
    </entity-mappings>
```

However, when I try to start my application, I get an error.  Digging through the stack trace gives me this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.blah.mapdb.repository.ResultRepository
```

Here's my repository class:

```
package com.blah.mapdb.repository;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.blah.mapdb.model.*;

public interface ResultRepository extends CrudRepository<Result, Long> {
      @Query(name="getMapForTarget",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Result> getMapForTarget (@Param("p1") String d, @Param("p2") String t, @Param("p3") String c);
...
}
```

And here's the relevant bits of the Result class:

```
package com.blah.mapdb.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Result {

    @Id
    private int id;
...
}
```

Clearly the result class has an Id defined.  If I include the query in the ResultRepository class, everything works fine.  I have no idea why I'm getting that error about the ResultRepository class.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your `orm.xml`:

```
<entity class="com.blah.mapdb.repository.ResultRepository">
```

this seems to be erroneous, you should have

```
<entity class="com.blah.mapdb.model.Result">
```

instead. Also, your table name definition is probably wrong, you should specify the actual table name you have your `Result` entity mapped to.